# Is EXTRA_PLUGGED always BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS on watches with wireless cradle?

Tags: android, wear-os

Can someone answer this question for me?

On watches that use wireless charging, does the extra `BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED` only every yield `BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS`? (as opposed to `BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC` and `BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB`).

```java
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

// How are we charging?
int extraPlugged = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, you may be getting that because `(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);` is set to `-1`. There are other number codes with corresponding equivalents like 0 is for "Battery".

More info from this [BatterManager docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_PLUGGED)

> EXTRA_PLUGGED
>
> added in API level 5 String EXTRA_PLUGGED Extra for
>   ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: integer indicating whether the device is
>   plugged in to a power source; 0 means it is on battery, other
>   constants are different types of power sources.

Answer (score 0):

For all practical purposes, yes, but watches that are plugged in via a debug board (i.e not the ones in the general public) can return `BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB`.